# Unpack only the first few columns from the CSV reader?

Tags: python, csv, iterable-unpacking

When reading a CSV file:

```
with open("foo.csv") as foo:
    for (a,b) in csv.reader(foo):
        ....
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

when the file contains more than two columns.

**Is there a way to unpack the first two columns and ignore the rest?**

I guess I can do

```
with open("foo.csv") as foo:
    for row in csv.reader(foo):
        a,b = row[0:2]
        ....
```

but that looks ugly.

PS. I am using python2, if that matters.

Comment: I think the answer depends on the version of python you're using, as there's an easy solution in python3 which doesn't exist in python2 (to the best of my knowledge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generator:

```
with open("foo.csv") as foo:
    for a,b in (r[0:2] for r in csv.reader(foo)):
         ...
```

This more clearly displays your intent. It's basically equivalent to your "ugly" way of doing it, but it's much easier to look at.

Answer (score 1):

In python2 there doesn't seem to be any mechanism to limit number of columns returned by `csv.reader`. I've checked sources of [`cpython 27` -> `csv.Reader_iternext()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c3ec90a6526e/Modules/_csv.c#l783) and the only possibility of ending row reading (I've just spent few moments analysing the code) is to encounter one of characters: `\r\n\0`.

You also can use [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

> If the row read has more fields than the `fieldnames` sequence, the
>   remaining data is added as a sequence keyed by the value of `restkey`.
>   If the row read has fewer fields than the `fieldnames` sequence, the
>   remaining keys take the value of the optional `restval` parameter.

So you can do:

```
with open("foo.csv") as foo:
    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile=foo, fieldnames=('a', 'b')):
        a = row['a']
        b = row['b']
        ....
```

But I personally would go with checking length of the row and using `(a,b) = row[:2]`.

Answer (score 1):

In python3 you should be able to do this:

```
with open("foo.csv") as foo:
    for row in csv.reader(foo):
        a,b,*unused = row
```

But since you use python2, if you assure that every line has at least 3 columns you can do this:

```
with open("foo.csv") as foo:
    for line in foo:
        a,b,*unused = line.split(',', 3)
        # splits every line by separator ','
        # but stops splitting after the first two   (maxsplit)
```

Or you can just use `pandas`, somehow like that:

```
import pandas

dataframe = pandas.read_csv("foo.csv", usecols=[0,1])
```